# How to Create Div id dynamically using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my code:

```
function getcategory(id){
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        method: 'post', 
        data: {
            id: id, 
            cat: 'category'
        },
        success: function(result){
            $("#category").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

How to create `#category` to `#category1`, `#category2`, `#category3` when I click a button?

Comment: Can you make it more clear?

Comment: What is the `result` of the ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

You could append div element with id(counter) to in success method before appending result to html()

This will add a new child div in category div and print result in that

```js
var counter=0;
function addDiv()
{
 counter++;
    $("#cat").append("<div id='counter"+counter+"'></div>");
    $("#counter"+counter).html("<h>Hello All</h>");
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cat">
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="addDiv()" value="add">
```